# Generate type declarations for create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I can't seem to get my create-react-app with typescript to generate declaration files. A `.d.ts` file should be added to the `build` folder when building. Adding `"declaration": true` to the `tsconfig.json` didn't change it.
To reproduce create a new app with `npx create-react-app --template typescript` and build it with `yarn build`.

I also tried `npx tsc --declaration` and `npx tsc --declarationOnly` and didn't get the file either.

How would I get a new or already existing create-react-app to generate a `.d.ts` declaration file upon building?

Edit: I declaration files, because this project can be used as a library.

Comment: I think I don't understand your question. Why do you want a d.ts file in your build folder? The browser doesn't understand typescript only javascript.

Comment: @Karlan see edit. The project can be used as a library. That's why I need the declaration files.

Comment: What I understand of it, create react app is not really made for publishing components to npm as a library. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#publishing-components-to-npm
(scroll to the end). Maybe this article can help you: https://medium.com/@carlosthe19916/create-react-app-cra-and-publish-your-library-components-to-npm-typescript-storybook-67ff8fe1599e